# Rails nested Resources not working in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-resources

I have this nested resource:

```
resources :services do
  resources :users  do
    put "assign" => "services#users#assign", as: :assign
  end 
end
```

My form contains this:

```
<%= button_to 'submit', service_user_assign_url(service.id, abstractor.id), method: :put %>
```

this generates the following url, which looks fine to me:

```
http://localhost:3000/services/1/users/2/assign
```

and the following is in my services controller:

```
def assign
  @service = Service.find(params[:service_id])
  @service.users << User.find(params[:user_id])
  redirect_to dashboards_path
end
```

However I get this error:

```
 The action 'users' could not be found for ServicesController
```

I'm not sure what this means - I have a has and belongs to many relationship between users and services and I am trying to associate an existing user to a service

Comment: This may be due to the "services#users#assign".  I've never seen that.  Did you mean "services#assign" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell rails if this action is a member action or a collection action, from the url you mentioned that you want to use, it's a member action:

```
resources :services do
  resources :users  do
    member do
      put :assign
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Basically correct except is member instead of members